# which web performance monitoring service is best?

Tags: performance-monitoring

which web performance monitoring service is best?

internetvista.com?
watchmouse.com?

Comment: Define "best" .

Answer (score 3):

You didn't list any real criteria.  Both Pingdom and Cloudkick are adequate, although Cloudkick is focused more on cloud server management.  Pingdom is too lightweight for my tastes, as they abstract a lot of the metrics, don't offer a wealth of checks, don't allow you to import external metrics, and have very limited correlation features.

Circonus (http://circonus.com/) is much better IMHO if any of these limitations affect you.  It stresses metric collection (rather than "availability") which you can then set rules and notifications to determine whether a service is "healthy" or not.  And you can import virtually any external metric (using the Resmon XML check, e.g. user registrations).  They have videos online showing off some of their features.

Answer (score 2):

If you host in the cloud, check out CloudKick.  It also works for dedicated servers.

---

Edit: CloudKick monitors by agent and it is very lightweight to install.  It comes with a web interface to track all of your cloud nodes.  If you go cloud, I recommend RackSpace.  They have a slighty better performance over Amazon in terms of CPU and their pricing structure is easier to understand imho.  Let me know if you want to try them out.  I have a referral link for you as I'm an affiliate as well as an avid user.

Edit 2: I second using PingDom as well, though I don't have much experience with Nagios.  In my experience, if you really have a big setup, have a separate node dedicated just for stats (Nagios & Others), but me personally, I prefer to just have that handled off-site.  Let someone else muck with the task of monitoring.  Just send me a txt to my phone, I'm good. lol

Truthfully, there are many options for you, my friend, and there is no wrong choice.  Just do your normal rigor of research and you will be alright.

** Just a cool tip, CloudKick allows you to remotely SSH into your machines from their website.  Super cool if you ask me...and convenient.

Comment: very cool!

and I want to know how CloudKick can monitor my server CPU? by SNMP or Agent?

Comment: Check out pingdom as well.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what your actual needs are, you might want to check out Nagios (http://www.nagios.org/).

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is still looking at this, and you happen to be looking for just HTTP monitoring (as I was), I found that http://monitorius.com has a very nice package that is more affordable than those listed above that do more than just simple HTTP monitoring.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few others:

AlertSite: http://www.alertsite.com - this is the best external monitoring service I've used, but they can get expensive. They have a nice transaction monitoring service called DejaClick. You record a "macro" of actions using a FireFox extension and upload it to AlertSite, and they run these macros at regular intervals. It's nice for e-commerce sites, to test an entire checkout flow - or any site that needs to check an entire process.

AlertFox: http://www.alertfox.com - It's newer, and a little bit rough around the edges still in terms of its user interface, but much cheaper and reliable. They also do transaction monitoring (they make the iMacros extension for Firefox).

We use both of these services for different sites, and I've had good experiences with both.